# java poi, How to get background fill colour from poi

Tags: apache-poi

Can anyone help me get the background fill colour for an excel cell using poi?
This is what I have done, it doesn't seem to work. I am using poi-3.15, all l get is 64.

```
int color = cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor();
```

[image]

Comment: l have included an image of what l done

Comment: click on "enter image description here"

Comment: At first I doubt you really wants the `FillBackgroundColor` since this the **index** of the  color **behind** the pattern. I suspect you wants the `FillForegroundColorColor` which is the color of the pattern fill. See [CellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getFillForegroundColorColor--) versus [CellStyle.getFillForegroundColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getFillForegroundColor--).

Comment: Thanks...l tried getting the fill-background color in excel by using the fillforegroundcolor. _it worked_...but in excel the button is described as fill back-ground color.

Answer (score 0):

//To anyone who is also facing the same problem...get fill-background-color...
//this is what l did

```
public void test3() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    XSSFWorkbook wk = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wk.getSheetAt(0);

    try{ 
        CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B2"); 
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 
        XSSFCellStyle cs = cell.getCellStyle();
        XSSFColor colour = cs.getFillForegroundColorColor();

        System.out.println(colour.getARGBHex());

    }catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Not edited or found!!!");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wk.close();
    fis.close();

}
```